# Google Calendar API event insert always return 404 "not found" error

Tags: google-calendar-api

I tried the calendar insert example from here : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples
    No matter which property i use, i always get the 404 "not found" error. Anyone can shed some light on this? Many thanks!!!

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/test/events?sendNotifications=false&fields=start&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.AHES6ZQaT3-Tj_bviwaY9Xi3gDspuBbCtEKtidnZkTXuWpI
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "end": {
  "date": "2012-07-11"
 },
 "start": {
  "date": "2012-07-09"
 }
}
```

response:
404 Not Found

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe it's telling you that the calendar "test" resource cannot be found. Have you created a calendar called "test"? If you replace "test" with "primary" (your main calendar) then the Explorer should work.

Comment: I have the same problem, I can't use the primary calendar, I need connect to other calendar.

Comment: @Matt Healy: I am not getting private event. I am authenticate user before call get event event list API. Is there any way so I can get private event as well?

Answer (score 10):

Today I had the same problem with non primary calendar. It's solved now, follow this steps:

1. Go to [Service Accounts](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts), enter to your project, and create a Service account, then go to Key Tabs and create one Key, a Json file is saved now.

[image]

[image]

2. Open Json and look at *"client_email"* attribute.

[image]

3. Now go to your non primary calendar and go to *Settings and sharing* section.

[image]

4. Now add the email it's set on *"client_email"* json attribute in the *Share with specific people* section.

[image]

5. Test again, it's now working!

Note: This solution serve me with PHP web app with *Service account* auth method. You have to use *Service account* method too instead of *OAuth 2.0*.

Comment: Hi were you able to add the attendees as well to the event using service account?

Comment: Hi! I'm not working with attendees, but maybe this reference will help you to reach [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)

Answer (score 6):

To JuanPablo, Re non-primary calendar:

In case of **non-primary calendar** you have to use the *id* (in form of an email address) as the *calendarId*.

Example:
Let's say you have a calendar named 'test'. You get its *id* like this

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
->
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendarList",
...
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
   "etag": ...,
   "id": "123example123example123xxx@group.calendar.google.com",
   "summary": "test",
   "description": "Testing calendar for development of Calendar related applications",
...
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Your POST will then look like this

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/123example123example123xxx@group.calendar.google.com/events?sendNotifications=false&fields=start&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be two problems:
a). Either your calendar id is not correct. You can find it via following steps-

1. In the Google Calendar interface, locate the "My calendars" area on the left.
2. Hover over the calendar you need and click the downward arrow.
3. A menu will appear. Click "Calendar settings".
4. In the "Calendar Address" section of the screen, you will see your Calendar ID. It will generally your mail id or primary.

b) Daily limit of unauthenticated use may have exceed. Check it via 
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary12/events?alt=json
primary12 is your calendar name

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

I was sending request using guzzleHttp (I mean not any official SDKs)

One of my calendar's id is `en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com` . and I needed to encode URL because of hashtag.

Answer (score -3):

I am also getting the same problem with s=inserting the event, while getting a particular event. But i got an alternative just specify 
CalendarList asa = service.CalendarList.List().Execute();
before the execution of code where you are getting. I don't know the reason why it is running after specifying this code. If you find the correct way please update it here as it will consume more quota count.

Comment: There is nothing related to code as he is hitting URL which can be from any HTTP client.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.  It should be removed.